# Iterated integral numerically

Tags: numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I am trying to calculate a double integral. However, after a long time, Mathematica does not give me any outputs. Has someone any ideas how to calculate this?

```
c0 = Sqrt[3];
a2 = 1;
ap2 = 1;
a1 = 1;
ap1 = 2;
m = 0.5;
pp = 0.5;
Kp[s_] := 
FullSimplify[ArcTan[a1  s]/ArcTan[ ap1  s] - m];
NIntegrate[Cos[NIntegrate[Kp[s], {s, 0.001, S0}]], {S0, 0.001, 1.5}]
```

Comment: Should `S0` be defined?

Comment: @MelaGo S0 is the variable that is integrated over in the outer integral

Comment: Concerning  the notions, this is not a double integral, but an iterated integral.

Comment: Should the integration limits be zero? Mathematica can deal with removable singularities in integration limits, and there's no need to move them artificially to a small non-zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: first, make the list with the values of the internal integral, and then interpolate the result and integrate the interpolation function:

```
c0 = Sqrt[3];
a2 = 1;
ap2 = 1;
a1 = 1;
ap1 = 2;
m = 0.5;
pp = 0.5;
Kp[s_] := FullSimplify[ArcTan[a1 s]/ArcTan[ap1 s] - m];

lst = ParallelTable[{S0, Cos[NIntegrate[Kp[s], {s, 0.001, S0}]]}, {S0,0.1, 1.5, 0.1}]

(* {{0.1, 1.}, {0.2, 0.999999}, {0.3, 0.999991}, {0.4, 0.999957}, {0.5,0.999856}, {0.6, 0.999626}, {0.7, 0.999187}, {0.8, 0.998444}, {0.9,0.997293}, {1., 0.99563}, {1.1, 0.993348}, {1.2, 0.990345}, {1.3,0.986525}, {1.4, 0.981799}, {1.5, 0.976084}} *)
```

Then let us interpolate this list:

```
f = Interpolation[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 3]

Show[{
  ListPlot[lst],
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0.1, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
```

[image]

And now let us integrate it:

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0.1, 1.5}]

(*  1.39306  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: @azerbajdzan No I made no mistake. If you look attentively through my code you will see that I started the list from S0=0.1. I did it to spare my time. It is from this point that I calculated the second integral. If I interpolated from 0.1, I cannot then integrate it from 0.01. If one starts from S0=0.01, it is reasonable to make the corresponding step in Table. This will be time-consuming. The author has a reason to solve this integral issue accurately. He can therefore, spend time to calculate it carefully. My task is only to show the way.

Comment: @azerbajdzan What are you disputing about? Do not you understand what I said?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your improved code  (For example, `FullSimplify` does nothing.).

```
ap2 = 1;a1 = 1;ap1 = 2;m = 1/2;pp = 1/2;
f[S0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[pp  ap2] ArcTan[a1  s]/ArcTan[ap1  s]-
 m, {s, 0.001, S0}]
Plot[{Evaluate[NIntegrate[Cos[f[S0]], {S0, 0, S}]], 
Evaluate[NIntegrate[Sin[f[S0]], {S0, 0, S}]]}, {S, 0, 2}]
```

[image]