# Integral within another integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, variable

I have to evaluate the following integral:

$I(k) = \int^{42}_{0} dt \hspace{0.1cm} 3t^3*e^{i \int_{0}^{t}dx( x^2 - \sqrt{x^4+k^2/x}) }/\sqrt{t^4+k^2/t}$

The answer in : [Iterated integral numerically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300925/iterated-integral-numerically)
seems to be working, however, I don't know how to generalize it with the extra k variable.

Comment: Have you tried to just evaluate the functions themselves yet to see what might the issue be? Are you sure that you want *indefinite* integrals here rather than definite integrals? Etc.

Comment: I tried indefinite integrals and then taking the limit because I have seen that gives results faster. I have plotted the real part of the integral which seems to be monotonically rising with time, while the imaginary part is monotonically decreasing

Comment: Try: `f[k_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(
  3 E^(1/3 I (x^3 - 
      6 Sqrt[k^2 x]
        Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/10, 11/10, -(x^5/k^2)])) x^3)/
  Sqrt[k^2/x + x^4], {x, 0, 42}]; ReImPlot[f[k], {k, 0.077, 1}]`

Comment: Unfortunately I got a failed attempt with this